# Create a valid PDF from a web request

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, scanning

I'm trying to create a scanning solution. Basically the user is physically scanning a page. The printer is making an API call, passing in the binary data of the scan in the body.

I'm trying to save this as a PDF on the server, but when I go to open the file, i'm getting an error "There is an error while reading a stream".

```
var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
string pathToFiles = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\UploadedFiles\\WriteLines.pdf");
try
{
    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(pathToFiles, false))
    {
        outputFile.WriteLine(bodyText);
    }
    
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw (ex);
}
```

This is just testing something, and I have permissions etc for writing the file, it's just not creating a valid file.

Any thoughts on what I should use? I have looked into some libraries, but they don't seem to cover what i'm after

Comment: Are you sure the printed send a PDF (and not a image) to your api?

Comment: Yes, 100% sure it's sending a pdf

Comment: Try a text file to see if the mechanics of your code works in general. Then if it works you know a little better where to focus.

Comment: I know the mechanics of the code works. I am generating a file and when I view it in notepad++ I can see the pdf headers in the document as I would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StreamReader.ReadToEnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readtoend) convert bytes to string in particular encoding (UTF8 by default). I don't think this work for PDF.

You need copy bytes directly in the output file :

```cs
var bodyStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
string pathToFiles = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\UploadedFiles\\WriteLines.pdf");
using (FileStream outputFile = File.Create(pathToFiles))
{
    bodyStream.CopyTo(outputFile);
}
```